# How does one make this code cleaner?

Tags: java, android, string

I'm working with 2 activities. One activity has a textView and a button. The textView shows the hobbies, which will be set if the user clicks the button. When the user clicks the button, he/she will go to the second activity which has 4 checkboxes corresponding to hobbies. When the user clicks Done from a menu, he/she will go back to the first activity, afterwhich, the checked hobbies will be shown in the textview, separated by commas (","). My problem is that, when the user sets the hobbies using the button again, but already has hobbies showing in the textView, the checkboxes in the second Activity should be initialized according to what is shown in the textView. I have tried arrays, even hardcoding, but I am stuck in a logical rut. Here is my code. Assume all views have been initialized:

1st Screen (important bit):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SET_BIRTHDAY:
            TextView textBirthday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBirthdayStat);
            birthdayString = data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588birthday.MONTH)
                    + "/" + data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588birthday.DAY)
                    + "/" + data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588birthday.YEAR);
            textBirthday.setText(birthdayString);
            break;
        case SET_HOBBIES:
            TextView textHobbies = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHobbiesStat);
            anime = data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588hobbies.ANIME);
            games = data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588hobbies.GAMES);
            movies = data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588hobbies.MOVIES);
            books = data.getStringExtra(Lab2_082588hobbies.BOOKS);

            checkNull();

            textHobbies.setText(hobbiesString);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void checkNull() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (games == null) {
        hobbiesString = books + " , " + movies + " , " + anime;
    }
    if (anime == null) {
        hobbiesString = games + " , " + books + " , " + movies;
    }
    if (movies == null) {
        hobbiesString = games + " , " + books + " , " + anime;
    }
    if (books == null) {
        hobbiesString = games + " , " + movies + " , " + anime;
    }
    if ((games == null) && (anime == null)) {
        hobbiesString = books + " , " + movies;
    }
    if ((games == null) && (movies == null)) {
        hobbiesString = books + " , " + anime;
    }
    if ((games == null) && (books == null)) {
        hobbiesString = movies + " , " + anime;
    }
    if ((anime == null) && (movies == null)) {
        hobbiesString = games + " , " + books;
    }
    if ((anime == null) && (books == null)) {
        hobbiesString = games + " , " + movies;
    }
    if ((movies == null) && (books == null)) {
        hobbiesString = games + " , " + anime;
    }
    if ((movies == null) && (books == null) && (anime == null)) {
        hobbiesString = games;
    }
    if ((movies == null) && (games == null) && (anime == null)) {
        hobbiesString = books;
    }
    if ((games == null) && (books == null) && (anime == null)) {
        hobbiesString = movies;
    }
    if ((movies == null) && (books == null) && (games == null)) {
        hobbiesString = anime;
    }
}
```

The Second Screen:

```
private void startUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent startUp = getIntent();
    String receivedString = startUp.getStringExtra(HOBBIES_STRING);

    if (receivedString != null) {
        String[] separated = receivedString.split(",");
        if (separated.length > 0) {
            if (separated[0].equals("Anime")) {
                anime.setChecked(true);
            }
            /*----------------*/
            if (separated[0].equals("Computer Games")) {
                games.setChecked(true);
            }
            /*----------------*/
            if (separated[0].equals("Books")) {
                books.setChecked(true);
            }
            /*----------------*/
            if (separated[0].equals("Movies")) {
                movies.setChecked(true);
            }
            /*----------------*/
            if (separated[0].equals("Anime")&& separated[0].equals("Computer Games")) {
                anime.setChecked(true);
                games.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (separated[0].equals("Anime")&&separated[0].equals("Books")) {
                anime.setChecked(true);
                books.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (separated[0].equals("Anime")&&separated[0].equals("Movies")) {
                anime.setChecked(true);
                movies.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

    }
```

The code still doesn't run as expected. As you can see, I have used string split and string arrays, but using arrays makes it hard to handle because of extreme hardcoding and array index bounds problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the CheckNull method i would use the following

```
private void checkNull() {  
hobbiesstring = "";
if (games != null) 
  hobbiesstring += games;
if (anime != null)
  hobbiesstring += anime;
if (books != null) 
  hobbiesstring += books;
if (movies != null)
  hobbiesstring += movies;
}
```

For the second part I would use the following code

```
private void startUp() {  
Intent startUp = getIntent();  
String receivedString = startUp.getStringExtra(HOBBIES_STRING);  

if (receivedString != null) {  
    String[] separated = receivedString.split(",");  
    foreach(string sep in seperated){
      switch(sep){
        case "Anime":
          anime.setChecked(true);
          break;
        case "Movies":
          movies.setChecked(true);
          break;
        case "Books":
          books.setChecked(true);
          break;
        case "Games":
          games.setChecked(true);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The checkNull function returns hobbies fine but isn't separated by commas, nor a space

Comment: Then you can check if there is already something in hobbiesstring and do `hobbiesstring += ", ";` in between the other adds

Comment: Yes, this made the code a lot more cleaner and easier to handle. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can switch on a String in Java. You can only do it with ints or Enums.

Comment: Apparently you are right @HenriqueOrdine. Then it is just a simple conversion to some if...else if... probably.  
I'm a .NET developer for my main job and that's the problem of thinking switch case is working on strings.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to implement this functionality using `Preferences`. Let your second `Activity` be a `PreferenceActivity` and the checkboxes - `CheckBoxPreferences`. When the user checks/unchecks them the values are automatically saved in `SharedPreferences`. Then when you return to the first `Activity` you can simply display the values using booleans saved in the `SharedPreferences`. You can google for tutorials on `Preferences` and [here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)  a nice post on `SharedPreferences` that will also be useful. Hope this helps.

Comment: We aren't in shared preferences yet in our Android class. While I would want to use it, the specs sheet explicitly states to not use it

Comment: @Erasmus, It's a pity, cause the other solutions I can imagine look far less elegant, and why not learn to design your application properly from the start?

Comment: I can utilize Shared Prefs as a knowhow, but Shared Prefs isn't allowed for now in our class since it isn't in the specs. perhaps ina later lesson. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass a '`,`' to a StringTokenizer ?

It is no so important, but you can optimize like this

```
   if (games == null) {
            hobbiesString = books + " , " + movies + " , " + anime;

            if (books == null) {
                hobbiesString = movies + " , " + anime;

                 if (anime == null) {
                       hobbiesString = movies;
                 }

            }
    } else if(books == null) {
           ...
    } else ...
```